# ¿Cómo capturo la hora actual en una base de datos?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un problema de captura con mi gestor de base de datos, deseo insertar la hora actual de mi equipo en una tabla transaccional pero no conozco la forma de hacerlo.

Answer (score 2):

Para capturar solo la hora, sin fecha `SELECT RIGHT( CONVERT(DATETIME, GETDATE(), 108),8) AS Hora`

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar la funcion

[GETDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188383(v=sql.120).aspx)

En el insert aplicaría de la siguiente forma

```
INSERT INTO <tabla> (campo1, campo2, FechaActual) VALUES (@param1, @param2, GETDATE())
```

Si defines un campo del tipo `time` podrias usar el funcion `CONVERT (time, GETDATE())`

[Tipos de datos y funciones de fecha y hora (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms186724.aspx)